# how to write command for update sql in java programming

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I facing problem to write command of update sql/oracle in java programming. my database is oracle. I had tried this method, but its not working. No update happen. Anyone kindly please help me on this?

```
conn = ds.getConnection();

String updateQ = "update ANI_999 set First_Name='d.getName()',HouseNo='d.getAddr1()',StreetName='d.getAddr2()',AppartmentSuite='d.getAddr3()',Town_City='d.getTownCity()',State='d.getState()',Postal_Code='d.getPostalCd()',Country='d.getCountry()' where CALLER_ID = 'msisdn'";

stmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateQ);
int result = stmt.executeUpdate(updateQ);

conn.commit();
conn.close();
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  In an SSCCE, we could see what is happening to the exception output.

Comment: I am sorry, what is SSCCE?..I haven't heard before. Thanks for your concern..:)

Comment: Check the result returned by `executeUpdate`? Catch/log `SQLException`?

Comment: The first time that 'SSCCE' appears on this page, is a ***link*** to the document.

Comment: No you seems to me doing it wrong, try this : `String updateQ = "update ANI_999 set First_Name= ?,HouseNo=?,StreetName=?,AppartmentSuite=?,Town_City=?,State=?,Postal_Code=?,Country=? where CALLER_ID = ?";` , now `stmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateQ);` `stmt.setString(1, d.getName());` and so on. Try this, this will prevent SQL Injection attacks too, I guess.

Comment: You calling the function inside the String literal, compiler i guess is not smart enough yet in this age to determine it's a function call, inside the String Literal, if I am not wrong, as it appears to me that you calling Java Code from inside your String Literal.

Answer (score 4):

```
update ANI_999 set First_Name='d.getName()',HouseNo='d.getAddr1()',StreetName='d.getAddr2()',AppartmentSuite='d.getAddr3()',Town_City='d.getTownCity()',State='d.getState()',Postal_Code='d.getPostalCd()',Country='d.getCountry()' where CALLER_ID = 'msisdn'
```

`First_Name='d.getName()'` is going to be executed as it is, not going to replace with value from your method `d.getName()`, similarly for all other fields.

Instead try this:

```
String query = "update ANI_999 set first_name = ? where caller_id = 'msisdn'";

PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, d.getName());

int result = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: It doesnot work, when I try to print the value of result, it show this error "Invalid column index"..any help suggestion please..:)

Comment: I had tried this >>pstmt.setString(1, d.getName()); but I got the value of result is 0..means its not update anything. what should i do?

Comment: The first error was because of my mistake I had placed quotes around 1 which you have resolved, 2nd one can you check if 'select * from ANI_99 where caller_id = 'msisdn'' returns anything

Comment: my initial thought was msisdn is a hard coded values, is there a variable in your code called as msisdn ? Generally [msisdn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSISDN) means identifier for cellular phone

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
```

and,

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
```

and query final,

```
String updateQ = "update ANI_999 set First_Name='d.getName()',HouseNo='d.getAddr1()',StreetName='d.getAddr2()',AppartmentSuite='d.getAddr3()',Town_City='d.getTownCity()',State='d.getState()',Postal_Code='d.getPostalCd()',Country='d.getCountry()' where CALLER_ID = 'msisdn'";

if(st.execute(updateQ)) {
    System.out.println("UPDATE! SUCCESS");
}
```

I hope help you.

Comment: SQL is malformed. Check @mprabhat suggestion

Comment: thanks for your help, but I cannot use this command conn.setAutoCommit(true); , it says that I should declare first. what should I declare?..any helps please..thank you for your attention..:)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completing mprabhat answer you should use something like

```
String query = "update ANI_999 set first_name = ? where caller_id = ?"; 

PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); 
pstmt.setString(1, d.getName()); 
pstmt.setString(2, msisdn); 

int result = pstmt.executeUpdate(); 
conn.commit() // in case no autocommit is set.
```